# function on currently clicked raphael.js item

Tags: html, raphael

I am using `Raphael.js` for drawing some shapes and i would like to know how it is possible to select the current by clicking on it and fire a `click()` function.

I'm having this function:

```
function selectItem() { 
    console.log("selected" + this.id);
    rect.attr({
        fill: "#ff0"
    });
```

and I'm trying to use this:

```
this.click(selectItem);
```

as known Raphael uses its own click-function, and i thought `this` would work.
Unfortanetly it does not.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following to use Raphael's click() function, check the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CHUrB/297/)**:

This simple code uses `click()` function:

```
var paper = Raphael("area", 400, 400);
var r = paper.rect(100, 50, 80, 60, 10).attr({fill: 'yellow', stroke: 'red'}),
    c = paper.circle(200, 200, 50).attr({fill: 'yellow', stroke: 'red'});


r.click(function() {
    // add your console.log if needed
    r.attr({fill: 'red', stroke: 'yellow', "stroke-width": 2});
    c.attr({fill: 'yellow', stroke: 'red'});
});

c.click(function() {
    c.attr({fill: 'red', stroke: 'yellow', "stroke-width": 2});
    r.attr({fill: 'yellow', stroke: 'red'});
});
```

Now, if you want to use **`this`**, then remember that it only works when you are using it within the scope of element creation. You can either manually add this code for all your elements, or create couple of arrays to keep your elements in it. Then if you know the index of on which you want to apply `click()`, just call it by `arr[ind].click()`.

EDIT: look at this **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CHUrB/298/)**, i used this.

Comment: the problem with this is, that the shapes are drawed dynamically. which means i have, lets say 10 shapes with the same `var rect = paper.rect(100, 50, 80, 60, 10);` which means only the last i drawed is able to get the click event.

Comment: I added new DEMO with `this` above